# Cannot Build cvblobslib_v_8_3 with VS 2012 and Opencv 2.4.2

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cvblobslib

I am trying to build the [cvBloblsLib](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/cvBlobsLib) and have been unable to do so far.

I have tried to follow the instructions but I am missing something. Do I need to include the directories for OpenCV2.4.2 in cvBlobsLib? If I dont I get

```
blobcontour.h(6) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cv,h': No such file or directory
```

Which is in the origial cvblobslib file blobcontour.h

But if do include opencv include directories, I get

```
h:\opencv2.4.2\include\opencv\cv.h(63): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp': No such file or directory
```

And this happens in the orginal cv.h file.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using the prebuilt libraries from 2.4.2,

try to point your "Additional Includes" at:
h:\opencv2.4.2\build\include

instead of 
h:\opencv2.4.2\include

(h:\opencv2.4.2\include would work, too, but then you've got to *manually* add the opencv2\include and all the module-includes, too, like modules\core\include, modules\highgui\include, etc. )

Comment: And eventually got to fix the error now from the answer here http://answers.opencv.org/question/1450/problem-compiling-cvblobslib-with-opencv-242/   
which says to comment the line #define _SHOW_ERRORS in BlobsConfiguration.h

Comment: Marking yours answer as it guided me :) Thanks!